# iOS native Facebook Login fails for Mobile Safari authentication

Tags: facebook, mobile-safari

I have a native iOS app with Facebook Login integrated. The login flow works when the native Facebook app is installed.

However, when I delete the app, the FB login fallback on FB Mobile Safari webapp. The app switching works fine, but when controls come back to my app, the state of the session is declared FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed.

I am using Facebook SDK v3.5.2 as of June 6th, 2013
Using iPad1 iOS5.1.1

```
    /*
     * Opens a Facebook session and optionally shows the login UX.
     */
    - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"email",
                    @"publish_actions",
                                nil];
        BOOL result = NO;
        FBSession *session =
        [[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID:nil
                             permissions:permissions
                         urlSchemeSuffix:@"<MySchemeSuffix>"
                      tokenCacheStrategy:nil];


        if (allowLoginUI ||
            (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)) {
            [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
            [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView
                    completionHandler:
             ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
             {
                 [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
             }];
            result = session.isOpen;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /*
     * If we have a valid session at the time of openURL call, we handle
     * Facebook transitions by passing the url argument to handleOpenURL
     */
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
                openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
             annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
        //return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
        BOOL urlWasHandled = [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                      fallbackHandler:^(FBAppCall *call) {
                                          // handle deep links and responses for Login or Share Dialog here
                                      }];

        return urlWasHandled;
    }

    /*
 * Callback for session changes.
 */
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen:
            if (!error) {
                if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
                    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
                        //Application specific code goes here.
                        }
                    }];
                }
                // We have a valid session
                NSLog(@"User session found");
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed:
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened to fix the issue.

The bug was, I was requesting read and write permissions in the same call.
Taking out the "publish_actions" from permissions solved the issue.

I tested Facebook Login in iOS6+ through native FB login, native FB app, and webapp.
Also tested on iOS5.1.1 through native FB app, and webapp.